# Convergence of a metric on $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. For each $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, we define a metric on $\mathbb{R}^k$ by

$$\|x-y\|_{p} := \left(\sum_{I=1}^k |x_i-y_i|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}\ \ \ \  x,y \in \mathbb{R}^k$$

with $\|x-y\|_{\infty} := max\{|x_i-y_i|:1 \leq i \leq k\}$

i) Using properties of limits, prove that for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^k, \lim_{p \to \infty} \|x-y\|_{p} = \|x-y\|_{\infty} $ and that $\forall p,q \in [1,\infty]$ any open set A in $(\mathbb{R}^k, \|\cdot\|_{p}) $ is also open in $(\mathbb{R}^k, \|\cdot\|_{\infty}) $

Comment: What is your try on the question?

Comment: I prove that $ \lim_{p \to \infty}  \|x-y\|_{p} = \|x-y\|_{\infty} $ using squeeze but the main issue I had was whether the proof to the second part of i) was correct. what I did was I considered balls of a fixed radius epsilon in both the first metric and the second metric, and the ball of epsilon in the first metric is contained in the second ( because $\|x-y\| _{p} \geq \|x-y\|_{\infty}$, and the epsilon ball of the second metric is contained in the ball of $\epsilon*k^\frac{1}{p}$ in metric p.  I tried taking the contrapositive, but got stuck. I was wondering if its the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Outline:

- First prove $\|.\| _\infty  \leq \|.\| _p$
- Next  prove $\|.\| _p  \leq \sqrt[p]{n} \;\|.\| _\infty$
- Combine the above two and take the limit as $p \to \infty$

---

Proof of second bullet :$$\vert x_k -y_k \vert^p \leq \max_{1\leq k\leq n} \left(\vert x_k-y_k \vert^p \right)=\|x-y\|^p_{\infty}$$

Summing in $k$ and the taking the $p$ th root gives the desired inequality!

Similarly deal with the first one

Comment: Thank you very much!